# Using JavaScript print the numbers from 1to20 and replace the number 2(two) with foo and 3(three) with boo and 12(twelve) as 1foo and t3 as 1boo?

Tags: javascript

I had done some process but the numbers are printing from 1 to 20 but it is just printing the numbers and displaying the foo,boo in place of 2 and 3. But it is not displaying 12 and 13. And this is my html and css code

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" href="task1.js"></script>-->
    </head>
      <body>
       <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">button</button>
        <input type="text">
         <script>
           function myFunction()
             {
                for(var i=1;i<21;i++)
                 {
                   if(i===2)
                     {
                       console.log("foo");
                     }
                       if(i===3)
                        {
                         console.log("boo");
                        }
                       console.log(i);
                   }
                }
        </script>
     </body>
  </html>


    This is my css code:
       function myFun()
        {
    console.log("Hello")
      }
```

Comment: CSS code? What stuff?

Comment: Please don't tag-spam. This has nothing to do with HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `else` keyword, which provides the path to follow if a condition *isn't* true:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    if (i === 2) {
        console.log("foo");
    }
    else if (i === 3) {          // ***
        console.log("boo");
    }
    else {                       // ***
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

You can also use `switch`:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    switch (i) {
        case 2:
            console.log("foo");
            break;
        case 3:
            console.log("bar");
            break;
        default:
            console.log(i);
            break;
    }
}
```

If you also want to replace `12` with `"1foo"` and `13` with `"1bar"`, it's trivial to add those cases above.

---

If you want to swap the **digits** `2` and `3` with `"foo"` and `"bar"`, even when they're in a number like 12 or 13, it's probably simpler: Convert to string and then do a replace; but note that `20` will be affected as well:

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    console.log(String(i).replace(/2/g, "foo").replace(/3/g, "bar"));
}
```

Comment: but it is okay sir!!............. i wanted to display 12(twelve) as 1 foo and 13(tirtheen) as 1boo

Comment: but it is okay sir!!............. How can i wanted to display 12(twelve) as 1 foo and 13(tirtheen) as 1boo

Comment: @saikrishna: See above.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a check for the last digit and pally the rest of the number for display.

```js
function  getTenth(i) {
    return Math.floor(i / 10) || ''; // prevent returning zero
}

var i;

for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 10 === 2) {
        console.log(getTenth(i) + 'foo');
        continue;
    }
    if (i % 10 === 3) {
        console.log(getTenth(i) + 'boo');
        continue;
    }
    console.log(i);
}
```

Bonus: a compact version with an object.

```js
var i, single, tenth;

for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    single = i.toString().slice(-1);
    tenth = i.toString().slice(0, -1);
    console.log(tenth + ({ 2: 'foo', 3: 'boo' }[single] || single));
}
```

Comment: That's what I was doing ! You can just replace your loop `for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++)` because he wants 1 to 20 ;)

Comment: @SteevePitis, what can i replace with what?

Comment: Your loop is 1 to 21 not 1 to 20 ;)